# what is the difference in these lines in order to get the pseudo element

Tags: selenium, pseudo-element

whats the difference between these two options to get the pseudo element or **what is the way to get these element** because one line holds an document.queryselector and the other line holds an array of elements

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#validationError'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')";
String content = (String) js.executeScript(script);
```

and

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String iconUrl = (String) js.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0],':before').getPropertyValue('content');", icon);
```

Comment: the 2nd line just uses "icon" as the value... whatever that is.

Comment: The first way is probably better / faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first statement, you are executing Javascript directly on a web element to get it's `:before` value. In the second statement, you are finding the web element with WebDriver, and then you are passing the element in as a parameter to JavaScript, to execute a script on it.

If `icon` and `#validationError` return the same element, then the scripts are functionally the same. The first uses JS to find the element, and the second uses Selenium to find the element, for subsequent use a parameter.

Comment: Thanks. 
is there option to use just in WebDriver to find the `::before` for example:
`WebElement elem = driver.findElement.By(id="exmp");`
`elem.driver.findElement.By(CSSValue = ::before);`

something like these?

Comment: Not really. I’ve struggled with this issue many times, and since it is a Javascript element, you can only locate it with JavaScript. I’ve never had success using just WebDriver.

Comment: it's not CSS element?
`WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.CSSSelector("#element"));`
and than
`elem.findElement(By.CSSSelector("::before"));`
These is not working?

Comment: Pretty sure that won't work --  have you tested it out in your code and does it work? I know ::before is a CSS selector but I don't think you can locate through Selenium using ::before. Never seen anyone have any success with that approach.

Comment: i tried to but i didn't succed, maybe i wrong with something, cause as far as i know the element itself is holding the ::Before so what actualy i need is the element and than to locate inside the element the ::Before, so the approach need to be twice, finding the element and than finding inside the element somehow